# Searching Python Lists

Tags: python, file, list, search

ok, i have this code:

```
colors = ["Red" , "Green" , "Blue" , "Pink" , "Purple" , "Cyan"]

search = str(raw_input())

found = "not"

if search in colors:
    print "Found!"
else:
    print "not Found"
```

so far, it can find one item in a list only if you type the string in the terminal exactly as it is in the list, that is the problem.

i need to be able to type one or two characters in the terminal and have it so that it lists the strings inside the list that matches the search (for example: if i were to type "P" the terminal, it would list "Pink" and "Purple" because they match my search so far, but not exactly)

I may be overlooking something but, is there a way i can search a list this way without having to have over 200 lines of code (200+ lines because what i need to implement this to has over 150 strings in the list) just for searching for the string?

Comment: Are you asking about a "search suggestion" like Google's auto complete ?

Comment: @squiguy yea, pretty much like that

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way, using a list comprehension:

```
matches = [color for color in colors if color.startswith(search)]
```

If you have a large list this might not perform so well.

Comment: would a list of about 200 strings (maybe 15 characters each) perform badly?

Comment: @RogerParishIII: Try it and see how well it performs.  That is the only way to be sure how fast code runs.  I only mentioned performance because I think there are faster ways to do this.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a proper data structure. From your requirement description, I think [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is just the one.

You build a trie with a list of colors and then search the trie with user inputs (prefix is allowed).
You can find diverse implementations on [github](https://github.com/search?q=trie%20python&ref=commandbar) or implement it yourself. :)

Answer (score 2):

if performance is not an issue, (ex: color list is small):

```
colors = ["Red" , "Green" , "Blue" , "Pink" , "Purple" , "Cyan"]
search = str(raw_input())
found = "not"

for color in colors:
    # or if color.startswith(search), depend on your needs
    if search in color:
        print "Found"

print "not Found"
```

otherwise, use Trie: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Answer (score 2):

You can use difflib standard Python library.

**Sample Code:**

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
colors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Pink", "Purple", "Cyan"]
search = str(raw_input())
for color in colors:
    s = SequenceMatcher(None, search, color)

    if s.ratio() > 0.25:
        print color
```

**Output:**

```
xxxx$ python foo.py 
p
Purple
```

**Note:**

You can manipulate the match ratio as per your needs. Here I have used a ratio of .25 and above for mining patterns.

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions will allow you to determine how much of the text and which part of it needs to be matched. The following will just search the start of the string.

```
import re

colors = ["Red" , "Green" , "Blue" , "Pink" , "Purple" , "Cyan"]
search = re.compile("^"+str(raw_input()))
isthere=[]
for col in colors:
    if search.findall(col)!=[]:
        isthere.append(col)

if isthere==[]:
    print "Nothing there"
else:
    print isthere
```

Answer (score 1):

```
search = str(raw_input())

matches = [s for s in colors if s.startswith(search)]
```

Then loop over matches and print.

Answer (score 1):

```
    for c in colors:
        if c[0:len(search)-1] == search:
            print "Found!"
```

Not the absolute most elegant solution, but it gets the job done. Just loop over the list and compare the relevant substrings. Admittedly, you might want to wrap this in a try/catch block for a KeyError in case the search string is longer than any element in colors.